# How do i look at my minecraft screenshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I take screenshots of cool stuff on minecraft but i don't know how to look at them or access them can someone help me out?

Comment: All of the screenshots are stored in `.minecraft\screenshots`. You can easily get there by opening the Resource pack folder and traversing up to the parent directory to find the screenshots folder

Answer (score 0):

On windows, all screenshots are saved to `.minecraft/screenshots`. To get to .minecraft click <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> and a program called 'run' will pop up. Then type in `%AppData%` then go to `roaming` and you should find it. Also, clicking 'saved screenshot as 'filename'' in game will bring you to the directory. On mac, [This Site](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/legacy-support/1758154-how-do-i-find-minecraft-screenshots-on-mac-d) says to go to the directory `/Library/Application Support/minecraft/screenshots`